# Dynamic panel with X times dummy and X times (1-dummy) variables

Tags: categorical-data, dynamic-regression

I have a dynamic panel model that goes as follows:
[image]

D is a dummy variable that takes the value of 1 if a condition is met in the previous period and zero otherwise.
Is this model correct? can I put dummy and 1-dummy for the same variable?

Answer (score 0):

This model is identifiable. We would usually code $β_3X_{it}(1 - D_{i,t-1})$ as just $β_3X_{it}$, but these lead to equivalent models.

Comment: assume D takes the value of 1 if the firm has  net income higher than its peers in the previous year and 0 otherwise.Y is net income of this year and X on the other hand is the debt of the firm,  Can I interpret positive and significant beta 2 as follows: firms that outperform peers in the previous period increase their debt to increase their net income. Similarly , if beta 3 is insignificant can I say that firms that don't outperform their peers tend not to increase their debt to boost profitability?

Comment: I will post is as a separate question

Comment: @wesso Okay. Don't forget to accept this answer if it answered your original question.